# create common reusable alert in ionic5

Tags: alert, box, ionic5

I am new to ionic and I want to create a custom alert box, and want to use in every page with different header and message. I want to create separate component for it and want to pass header and message value.
Could you please suggest me what is the correct way of doing it.

This is my code :

```
async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'alertCustomCss',
      header: 'Confirm Action',
      message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this <div><img src = "./assets/icon/alert-circle-outline.svg" width="35px" height="35px"></div>',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'No',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'cancel-btn',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel);
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Yes',
          cssClass: 'ok-btn',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Okay');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

I want to place this code in separate component and want to make it reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a service for that.

Place the alert function to your service like this

```js
async presentAlertConfirm(header: string, massage: string) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'alertCustomCss',
      header,
      massage,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'No',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'cancel-btn',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Yes',
          cssClass: 'ok-btn',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Okay');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
    return alert;
  }
```

Then you can use this function anywhere you import your service. 
(I didn't test the code)

Comment: For a reusable alert code, it would be helpful to be able to pass handler functions, buttons and corresponding texts as arguments to the alert function.  When I tried to pass a handler function (referencing it by name) as an argument to an alert function, the handler function got executed before I was able to click on one of the buttons.  Any idea how to prevent such behavior?  I would've liked for the handler function to execute after clicking on one of the buttons.